# Cannot retrieve Value with ID of 133705167

Tags: graphdb

When running a `SPARQL UPDATE query (DELETE/INSERT)` the message :

> Cannot retrieve Value with ID of 133705167

is given in the GraphDB workbench. This happened after a large update query successfully finished.

Any ideas as to why this message occurred?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Coild you send an email to graphdb-support with more details, including the query and the stacktrace that can be found in one of the the logs. The logs are located within 'logs' folder under the distribution folder.

Answer (score 0):

GraphDB database engine represents the RDF data into two parallel collections named entity pool and statement collections. The entity pool is a dictionary-like structure mapping the RDF values to the internal identifiers. The statement collections are the actual indexes storing the subject predicate object context data organised as a paged structure.

The exception `Cannot retrieve Value with ID of 133705167` indicates that the statement collections contains a value which cannot be retrieved from the entity pool. Few possible scenarios can lead to such inconsistency:

- The database collections were manually edited or copied while the database was running
- You hit an unknown database bug

I recommend you first to `scan` your image with the [storage tool](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/storage-tool.html). It will detect and report all data inconsistencies. Later once you determine the full scope of the issue, you can recover your repository content, by dumping it to RDF file with the `export`. All internal IDs without RDF value will be skipped.